# Is it possible to reduce the number of a character by one with a single regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace `&&` with `&` and `&` with nothing. There are never more than 2 consecutive `&`s.

Currently I have:

```
$m =~s/&&/££%££/g;
$m =~s/&//g;
$m =~s/££%££/&/g;
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this regular expression instead:

```
$m =~ s/&(&?)/$1/g;
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/SGvRH)

---

This version will also work with more than 2 ampersands:

```
$m =~ s/&(&*)/$1/g;
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/PRTwM)

Comment: And, if you wanted to generically reduce the number of `&`s by one, that'd be `s/&(&*)/$1/g`.

Comment: s/&(?!&)//g would delete a & from any number also.